# Why doesn't my bash prompt update?

Tags: git, bash, ps1

I'm new to git and I'm trying to add the current git branch to my already existing prompt, which is defined as follows :

```
RESET="\[\017\]"
NORMAL="\[\033[0m\]"
RED="\[\033[31;1m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[33;1m\]"
WHITE="\[\033[37;1m\]"
SMILEY="${WHITE}:)${NORMAL}"
FROWNY="${RED}:(${NORMAL}"
SELECT="if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \"${SMILEY}\"; else echo \"${FROWNY}\"; fi"

export PS1="${RESET}${YELLOW}\u@\h${NORMAL} \`${SELECT}\` ${YELLOW}\w $(__git_ps1) >${NORMAL} "
```

I tried it (by sourcing my `.bashrc` file again) and it seemed to work, but then I went on another branch and it did not update. How can I make sure the `$(__git_ps1)` is not cached?

Comment: I love the idea of having `:)` and `:(` in your prompt depending on whether the last command failed :)

Comment: @Mark Longair : I found it here : http://serverfault.com/questions/4889/what-are-some-informative-and-useful-shell-prompts-bash-csh-ksh-etc BTW, why did you delete your solution, it works too!

Comment: it was minutes later than the other two, and is less neat than @geekosaur's anyway

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this exact question (and, of course, to geekosaur for his answer)! I've been flailing around for HOURS trying to figure out why my prompt was only updating its git status line when I sourced my .bashrc file.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You need a backslash on the `$` so it isn't expanded immediately.  (Compare to the `` `...` ``, which is a different way of writing `$(...)`.)

```
export PS1="${RESET}${YELLOW}\u@\h${NORMAL} \`${SELECT}\` ${YELLOW}\w \$(__git_ps1) >${NORMAL} "
```

I would agree with @MikeSep about using single quotes, but it's actually a bit more optimal to let the colors and such be substituted immediately.  Not necessary, just somewhat better.  That said, it *is* easier to understand what's going on if you use the single quotes.

Comment: Also, if you ever work in things other than terminal programs directly (Emacs/Vim command buffers, `screen`, etc.), you might want to look into using `tput` instead of hard-coded color escapes.

Comment: It is necessary to have the colour variables be substituted in this case, I think - at least, I just get the escape codes with @MikeSep's suggestion, whereas your one works fine. (+1)

Comment: @Mark: That's interesting; the `${SELECT}` one demonstrates that recursive evaluation is being done.  Maybe it's only for commands?  I generally use a PS1 function instead because it's easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: man, you are a life savior. I have a question though: I have a MBP and an iMac. Same .bash_profile, same version of the bash (installed via homebrew). on the MBP if I don't add the \ in front of the `$(__git_ps1)`, it won't be evaluated. If I do the same thing on the iMac, it gets evaluated even without the \. Any idea how this can happen?

Comment: @molli could you let us know which versions of macOS/ OS X are running on your MBP and iMac? the same ones?

Answer (score 29):

Your `PS1` string is probably getting evaluated before it is getting saved, but you really want the `__git_ps1` command to run each time you get a command prompt. I'd recommend using single quotes instead of double quotes for your `export PS1='${RESET}...'` line.

Comment: may work, but I'm having problems converting all the system to single quotes, so I'll you use geekosaur's solution. But you get my upvote too.

Comment: Ah, yes. His is better -- I missed the local vars for colors. Thanks for the vote anyway. :)

Comment: putting simple quote instead of double quote saved me, thx :)